# Lock specific columns on change event of a cell with header filter and sort enabled in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, locking

There are 6 columns in the sheet, out of which first four are editable and last two columns should be locked.

[image: Column Header sort and filter option]

[image: This is what i want to achieve]

On changing any cell value of Col1 to Col4, date/time should be updated in Col5 (created on) and Col6 (last updated).

I did the following:

[image: Adding Range]

[image: Unlocking all selected cells]

[image: Locking Col5 and Col6 selected cells]

[image: Protecting sheet]

[image: Selecting other properties of Protect Sheet]

[image: Code]

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim myTableRange As Range

    Dim myDateTimeRange As Range

    Dim myUpdatedRange As Range

    'Your data table range
    Set myTableRange = Range("A2:D10")

    'Unprotect sheet
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Test@pass"

    'Check if the changed cell is in the data table or not.
    If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Column for the date/time
    Set myDateTimeRange = Range("E" & Target.Row)

    'Column for last updated date/time
    Set myUpdatedRange = Range("F" & Target.Row)

    'Determine if the input date/time should change
    If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then
    
    myDateTimeRange.Value = Now
    
    End If

    'Update the updated date/time value
    myUpdatedRange.Value = Now

    'Protect sheet
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Test@pass"

    End Sub
```

I am able to update Col5 and Col6 based on cell edited under Col1 to Col4, but sort and filter ability is lost of all Columns header.

How do i bring back the header sort and filter functionality after cell lock?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you protect a sheet you won't be able to sort the table any longer - although you chose the "AutoFilter"-option - this is kind of a bug. But Filtering should work ...